# class magento\framework\serialize\serializer\json does not exist

Tags: magento2, theme

I am trying to update my CleverSoft theme and I receive this in command line when I run this:

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

[image]

Comment: What version do you use?

Comment: 2.1.7 Magento Community Edition

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was having the same problem in Magento 2.1.8.

I solved the problem by cloning the latest version of the repository [GitHub](https://github.com/magento/magento2.git) and copying the 'Serialize' package to version 2.1.8.

Path: `<magento_path>/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Serialize/`