# Json does not exist for my custom module

Tags: magento2, module, json, home-page

```
Vendor name: SimplifiedMagento
Module name: MilkyMan

Class SimplifiedMagento\\MilkyMan\\Serialize\\Serializer\\Json does not exist"
```

***This thing is coming when i am loading my home page.***

Comment: Check if Class "SimplifiedMagento\MilkyMan\Serialize\Serializer\Json" exists. It should have a file created under app/code SimplifiedMagento\MilkyMan\Serialize\Serializer\Json.php

Comment: Does this answer your question? [class magento\framework\serialize\serializer\json does not exist](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/230722/class-magento-framework-serialize-serializer-json-does-not-exist)

Comment: It really looks like wrong namespace for Json class, It should be got from magento/framework, probably

Comment: Thank you guys...resolved!